# Getting time range in Python

Tags: python, logging, time

I want to get a time range, where start is start of previous hour, end is end of previous hour.
To do this i have the following method:

```
def get_time_boundaries():
   start = datetime.utcnow().replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) - timedelta(hours=1)
   end = start + timedelta(hours=1)
   return start, end
```

I'm using logger to check this methods results:

```
START_TIME, END_TIME = get_time_boundaries()
logger = get_logger(__name__)
logger.info(f'Time boundaries: {START_TIME} - {END_TIME}')
```

Logger's format is set `"%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s"`

That part of code starts regularly once per hour, and in logs a have found strange result:

```
2019-11-23 17:11:04,828 INFO jobs.sync Time boundaries: 2019-11-23 16:00:00 - 2019-11-23 17:00:00
2019-11-23 18:11:04,707 INFO jobs.sync Time boundaries: 2019-11-23 17:00:00 - 2019-11-23 18:00:00
2019-11-23 19:11:04,116 INFO jobs.sync Time boundaries: 2019-11-23 18:00:00 - 2019-11-23 19:00:00
2019-11-23 20:11:04,254 INFO jobs.sync Time boundaries: 2019-11-23 19:00:00 - 2019-11-23 20:00:00
2019-11-23 21:11:04,492 INFO jobs.sync Time boundaries: 2019-11-23 20:00:00 - 2019-11-23 21:00:00
2019-11-23 22:11:01,388 INFO jobs.sync Time boundaries: 2019-11-23 20:00:00 - 2019-11-23 21:00:00  <---------------
2019-11-23 23:11:04,905 INFO jobs.sync Time boundaries: 2019-11-23 22:00:00 - 2019-11-23 23:00:00
```

Does anybody have idea why could it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are calling this using a cron job or similar exactly on the hour this is just a result of whether the job runs before or after the hour. If it runs at 20:00:01 you will get 20:00:00 as your start time. If it runs at 20:59:59 you will also get 20:00:00. The solution is either to run it a little after the hour, or to add a few minutes to `utcnow()` so you always get the next hour.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments this doesn't appear to be the case unless the code is running for >10 minutes before it writes the logs. Maybe add some debugging by just getting the code to log the full datetime to see if it varies from the log time.

Comment: It looks like the cron job is running after the hour , the start of the lines show the code executes at 11min 4 secs past